# Building an atomic design development ecosystem in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, package.json

Lately we've been fascinated about the http://patternlab.io/ -approach for developing different kind of UI components. It seems really nice and approachable way to develop new products and to increase the reusage of the UI-components.

However, we are now stuck in building hell and have no really bright ideas how to solve it.

**Problem:**

```
my-awesome-project@0.0.1
├─┬ atoms
│ │ └── atom1
│ │ └── atom2
│ ├── molecules
│ │ └── molecule1 (depends on atom1 && atom2)
│ │ └── molecule2
│ ├── organisms
│ │ └── organism1 (depends of molecule1 & molecule2)
│ │ └── organism2
```

We're using *browserify* for transpiling our packages in to CSS & ES5.

When I update an `atom1`, I need to recompile `molecule1` and `organism1` and it's getting laborous. Are there any good practices how to build a manageable javascript ecosystem?

**Structure of the ecosystem:**

FirstAtom: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "first-atom",
   "main": "dist/js/index.min.js"
}
```

SecondAtom: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "second-atom",
   "main": "dist/js/index.min.js"
}
```

CombinationOfTwoAtoms: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "combination-of-two-atoms",
  "main": "dist/js/index.min.js"
  "devDependencies": {
    "first-atom": "file:../../atoms/first-atom/",
    "second-atom": "file:../../atoms/second-atom/",
  }
}
```

Comment: *"the manual rebuilding of each package"* – what does that mean exactly? Is there inherent complexity in managing dependencies, or is it merely a lot of work to *compile* everything? Can't you automate that? Is that what your question is about?

Comment: I updated the description with the picture of the hierarchy, which might answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually want to publish, version and manage each molecule, atom and organism separately, there's no need to put a `package.json` in each and manage them manually.

Keep your `package.json` at the root of the project, then specify dependencies with imports, rather than `devDependencies` (also, why use `devDependencies` surely you'd want these in production too?).

```
// first-atom.js
export default FirstAtom;

// second-atom.js
export default SecondAtom;

// first-molecule.js
import FirstAtom from '../atoms/first-atom';
import SecondAtom from '../atoms/second-atom';

// ...

export default FirstMolecule;
```

You can continue this dependency graph the whole way up to your organisms.  This way, whenever you build a version of your app, everything you need will be compiled in one pass.

Comment: We were looking for a good separation between packages, so that the each package is containing its own development environment. Also development environment would be really flat.

Comment: What's the reasoning for each package having it's own development environment? There's no need to make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: That would facilitate the development even for the juniors. So they don't need to be concerned about all the environmental stuff. Ideally they'd just need to `cd atoms/fix-me` then `npm install && gulp` and they'd have the browser open and component ready for the development with the tests & possible mock data.

Comment: But you can do that without making every component a package. `cd project && npm install` then use something like [carte-blanche](https://github.com/carteb/carte-blanche) to isolate the components for development.